# Images won't align with text on drop down

Tags: html, css

I've been creating a drop down menu and for some reason I can't for the life of me get the images and the text in the drop down to align with each other. The images will sit slightly lower or the text slightly higher. If anyone can point me in the right direction to sorting this frustrating issue, that would be incredible.

Thanks guys.

```css
#dropdown {
  display: block;
  background-color: fff;
  border-left: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-right: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-top: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 80px;
}

#dropdown p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#dropdown img {
  margin-left:30%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

#ddSets {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <div id="ddSets">
    <p><strong>Settings</strong></p><br>
    <img src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/MyAccount.svg" width="20px" height="20px" ondragstart="return false;">
    <p>My Account</p><br>
    <img src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/Sub-Users.svg" width="20px" height="20px" ondragstart="return false;">
    <p>Sub-User</p><br>
  </div>
  <div id="ddSets">
    <p><strong>Support</strong></p><br>
    <img src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/Email.svg" width="20px" height="20px" ondragstart="return false;">
    <p>Email Us</p><br>
  </div>
  <div id="ddSets">
    <img src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/Logout.svg" width="20px" height="20px" ondragstart="return false;">
    <p>Log Out</p><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
#dropdown img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
#dropdown {
  display: block;
  background-color: fff;
  border-left: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-right: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  border-top: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 80px;
}

#dropdown p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#dropdown img {
  margin-left:30%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#ddSets {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1dfe1;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
  <div id="ddSets">
    <p><strong>Settings</strong></p><br>
    <img src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/MyAccount.svg" width="20px" height="20px" ondragstart="return false;">
    <p>My Account</p><br>
    <img src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/Sub-Users.svg" width="20px" height="20px" ondragstart="return false;">
    <p>Sub-User</p><br>
  </div>
  <div id="ddSets">
    <p><strong>Support</strong></p><br>
    <img src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/Email.svg" width="20px" height="20px" ondragstart="return false;">
    <p>Email Us</p><br>
  </div>
  <div id="ddSets">
    <img src="http://pa2.sulmaxcp.com/IMAGES/Logout.svg" width="20px" height="20px" ondragstart="return false;">
    <p>Log Out</p><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do this simply with an icon set like FA:

```
<div id="dropdown">
  <div id="ddSets">
    <p><strong>Settings</strong></p><br>    
      <i class="fa fa-user" ondragstart="return false;"></i>
    <p>My Account</p><br>    
    <i class="fa fa-users" ondragstart="return false;"></i>
    <p>Sub-User</p><br>
  </div>
  <div id="ddSets">
    <p><strong>Support</strong></p><br>
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" ondragstart="return false;"></i>
    <p>Email Us</p><br>
  </div>
  <div id="ddSets">
    <i class="fa fa-sign-out" ondragstart="return false;"></i>
    <p>Log Out</p><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

just rename your img class to i (or create a i class) and claim a free Font Awesome embedd code.